# hub 6-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)

Tags: 22.04

My main system is Windows 11, I want to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my computer, but when I select try or install Ubuntu, I get an error, and there is no response.

[image]